# How to apply existing fade in effect code to new element

Tags: javascript, css, image, hover, fadein

When you hover over an image I have a javascript element pop up (top image) and a css coded popup. Is there anyway of applying the fade effect of the second to the first or any other way of having the top image fade in at all? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fade out the current image, change it, then fade it in:

```
$('img').fadeOut(100,function() {
    $(this).attr('src','newimg.png').fadeIn(100);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3j45B/2/